# Gaussian integral for complex prefactor

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gaussian-integral

Using integration by substitution you easily deduce
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-ax^2) dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
for $a>0$ from the case where $a=1$.

**Question 1:** Is there a similar way to prove the same formular for not only real $a>0$ but for $a \in \mathbb C$ with $\Re(a)>0$? Here I don't want to make use of the identity theorem.

**Question 2:** If you want to prove the equation using the identity theorem you need to argue that
$$ a \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-ax^2) dx$$
is holomorphic. How do you argue that?

**Side note:** WolframAlpha thinks that the equality even holds for $a=i$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%20exp%28-i%20x%5E2%29%20dx%20).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $a\in\mathbb{C},\,\text{Re}(a)>0.$. Then note that, integrating by parts, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}ax^{2}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)dx.$$Now define $$I\left(a\right):=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)dx.$$Then $$I^{\prime}\left(a\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{2}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)dx=-\frac{I\left(a\right)}{2a}$$ hence, solving the ODE, we get$$I\left(a\right)=\frac{c_{1}}{\sqrt{a}}$$ and so now it is enough to observe that $I\left(1\right)=c_{1}=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: So you say that the integral converges for $a=i$? How is this possible? The absolute value of the integrand is constant $1$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes, it works if $\mathrm{Re}(a)>0$.

Comment: In your argument you use already that $I(a)$ is differentiable and that you can drag in the derivative. You need to show that first. And then it seems to me to be too close to the question 2 (in question 1 I was looking for an answer without the use of holomorphy).

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I have not written all the steps, it is a sketch of how it could be proved. However, I don't think you can go too far from some form of regularity on $a$ to get to a conclusion.